# How to read huge .gz file in S3, as I'm getting memory error while reading

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip

I'm trying to read .gz files in S3 and there are total 120 files and I want to merge all the files into one single file.

P.s. the size of each file is between (419MB to 900MB).

```
output = []        
for i in files:
    if i.endswith('.gz'):
        obj = s3.Object(bucket_name=bucket ,key=i)
        with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=obj.get()['Body']) as gzipfile:
            content = gzipfile.read()
            output.append(content)
```

I'm getting MemoryError at this line  **content = gzipfile.read()**

Comment: If the file size range is as stated then let's assume an average size of 660MB. Now multiply that by 120 which gives you ~77GB. Is your machine capable of maintaining that much data (plus other overheads) in memory?

Comment: Got your point. Thanks! @OlvinRoght

Comment: There's nothing AWS or S3 specific in your post. This looks like code you are running after downloading some files from S3, at which point it's just about reading local files.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `gzipfile.read()`, use a loop to do `gzipfile.read(buffersize)`, where `buffersize` is some reasonable number of uncompressed bytes to load into memory and process. When you get no bytes back, then you exit your loop.